# Something is wrong with my jalapeno plant

Tags: jalapenos

Its delivering good fruit, although they seem to go red quickly, and also the leaves look really yellow. This photo is current and I'm in Sydney Australia.

Also, seems to be a small web with bugs in it near the fruit.

[image: My plant look sick]

Comment: How much do you water it? When you used fertilizers? Do you have some cats around? To me it seems lack of fertilizers or root problem or some acid (cat pee?). Could you add other information, like since when it changes colour?

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues.

One, this plant seems to have a deficiency - the yellowing inbetween the veines is not good. There are a multiple possible causes - amongst them iron deficiency, wrong ph and too much water - and it’s hard to diagnose without more information.

Two, the plant has a massive spider mites problem. The webbing is a clear indicator, as is the “dotted” discoloration.

The double stress triggers a “produce offspring before death” reaction, hence the growth of fruit despite less than ideal conditions.

I suspect a chicken-egg-issue. The plant is suffering, this makes it susceptible for insects, which im turn weakens it more... Whatever you do, you need a two-sided battle. Find the reason for the chlorosis and fight the spider mites. For both you may find a solution here on the site. Remember that you have to be careful if using pesticides on plants you want to eat later.

Answer (score 1):

If you have little bugs on web it is likely to be red spider mites also called 2 spotted spider mites. 
They eat away at the plant sap in very little time and can kill a plant which explains the yellowing of the leaves, the vascular system of the plant is quickly drying off(chlorosis)

Also, the fruits turn red very quickly because the plant knows it is dying and it tries to seed quickly( in the Chili) to make sure it’s genes are perpetuated.

A quick fix is to place the plant in the bath or outside and hose it down thorough to dislodge the mites. Make sure you hose the underneath of the leaves where the eggs and new mites are born.
Feed your plant with a liquid seaweed mix to give it a boost, spray your plant with a mix of aromatic oil such as lavender or rosemary oil mixed with a bit of soap and water.

However, it could be a lost cause, your plant looks quite bad!